# Stop Jenkins from running after unstable build

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job that runs multiple windows batch command.

The current situation is that after the first batch command exits, and is set as unstable, the Jenkins won't stop but it will run the next windows batch command.

E.g.

```
First windows batch command
Python sys_dir/test1.py
If %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
exit 0)
# this job has set if have errorlevel as 2, it will marked as unstable
```

```
Second windows batch command
Python sys_dir/test2.py
echo "Should not proceed the second batch if there have failure/unstable during the first windows batch command
```

Comment: I guess these are two different build steps. I'd put both commands in one step.

Answer (score 0):

See the ***Execute Windows batch command*** → *ERRORLEVEL to set build unstable*'s inline help:

> [...], the build results will be set to unstable and next steps will be continued.